# Any idea for tuning a model transformer with huggingface?

Tags: nlp

when I try to tuning a model with hugging face, training loss is very fast decrease to zero but when I test I got a very wrong result, I don't know why although I train so much epochs but the result not change
#this is my colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LlI6_a2dcyYpkWv_iYrgmscN-_CRIByC?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. The way it is written, your question is somewhat unlikely to attract answers. Could you rephrase the question to include a small reproducible example with code entirely in the question post? You can enclose python code between ````python3 and ``` ` to format it nicely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.